# How to DrawString Just after the Text in a Picture Box with out knowing the X and Y postions?

Tags: vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I am working in a VB6 to VB.NET migrated project.In VB6 I have a picture box in runtime design a form using the Graphics.Suppose I have a two labels lbl1 and lbl2 just to the right when we mousedown on the picture box showing a textbox to enter text.The Entered Text is Visible after the LostFocus in a Textbox.In VB6 after saving the data and reopening the same form the saved text is correct position showing right to the label .

In VB.NET it is not happening.In VB6 they have written just

```
picture1.Print "Hi".
```

But in VB.NET we need to write provide the position also.Could any one help me regarding this ?

Comment: you might want to include a screen shot (or a link to one), in order to help others understand exactly what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I solved my problem as given below.

Measured the label width as given below

```
                Dim stringSize As New SizeF

                Dim labelText as String=lbl.Text
                stringSize = eventArgs.Graphics.MeasureString(labelText,Font.TimeNewRoman
```